# configuring log4j to display errors

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I've configured my log4j.properties so that it puts all the info and debug messages in a separate log file in tomcat. However, when the application fails, say bad sql command then the errors don't show up in that file but instead show up in the regular localhost log file.

How can I configure the properties such that the errors show up in that file as well?

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, logfile

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapplog.log

log4j.category.org.springframework.web=INFO
log4j.category.com.package.app=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.samples.mvc31=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG
```

The type of errors I want to see in my log file are like these:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name...
```

Comment: Please show also the code you use to initialise your logger, and the code you use to output the log messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are catching the exceptions/errors(Throwable) and putting log.error statements in your catch blocks then only you will be able to see the exception messages in your log file. For all the exceptions that are not caught in your code will be basically pushed to the console logger of tomcat and hence you are seeing the exception traces in tomcat out log file.

So try to catch all the possible exceptions in your code and log them properly so that they appear in your log files.